# How to use "continued" at a bottom of a page?

Tags: expressions

I have several written papers, jumping from one topic to another, and I want to connect some of them by indicating that an argument will be deeply exposed elsewhere in the text.

What I want to write must express that something "continues on page (...)"; I guess I should write "continued on page (...)" but I'm not sure, so I wonder:

- How to use "**continued**" at a bottom of a page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to express that your are not finished with a topic:

> - More on this later.
> - This will be revisited in the X section.
> - Tune in next week for more on this.

And the typical newspaper style:

> - TOPIC NAME continued on page X

Be aware that as you edit documents the page numbers change.  Many word processors can manage that by tracking the page number as it changes if you take the time to learn to set it up.

None of them need to be placed at the bottom of the page.  Simply put them where discussion of the topic ends, before another topic is picked up.

Similarly, as @hmmn correctly comments, you can resume a topic with an introductory phrase that hints at the previous mention of the topic:

> - Resuming the previous discussion of X
> - As previously mentioned in section X ...
> - Last week, we left our heroes ...

And the typical newspaper style:

> - TOPIC NAME from page X

There is a formal name for these kinds of instructions.  They are called a:

> **Jump line**
>
> a directional line of print (as “continued on page 7, column 2”) at the end of the first part of a divided story or article in a newspaper or periodical or a line (as “continued from page 1”) at the continuation
>
> [merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jump%20line)

Newspapers and periodicals aren't the only mediums dealing with this issue of course but they seem to have given it a good name.  On the web, a closely related concept is a **hyperlink** which does much the same but the instructions are processed by your computer, rather than your brain.  Which explains some of the weirder entries in my browser history.

Comment: ^vote with a note: This answer is so good I don't want to duplicate it just to add the suggestion to be sure to have a matching "continued from" phrase where a topic resumes

Answer (score 2):

You could say any of these:

- More on this topic at page X.
- Tune in next issue for more about this!
- There will be more after the commercial break.

and then on that page/issue/part you could say:

- Continuing off from page X...
- During the previous issue...
- Before the commercial break...